# How to migrate data from some tables from one Oracle database to another?

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, migration

How to migrate data from some tables from one Oracle database to another in a real time (if a data is inserted in a table in oracle1.table1, I'd want it to be replicated to oracle2.table2 within 1 minute.

How would that be possible?

In SQL Server, I've seen how SSIS works but is there anything similar for Oracle to Oracle data migration?

Comment: you still can use ssis if you have, just create both database connections

Answer (score 1):

What you want is data replication. After an initial copy of the data, copy only the transactions on that data. For this, dbvisit replicate is a very smart tool. You could code this yourself to using streams but you can expect to build a less stable and in the end more expensive system than just buying a dbvisit replicate license. An other option is Oracle's Golden Gate but that is powerful and a bit pricey.

See [the dbvisit website](http://blog.dbvisit.com/category/database-replication/)

Answer (score 0):

You may probably try to look at [Data Pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm)

> Oracle Data Pump technology enables very high-speed movement of data
>   and metadata from one database to another. Oracle Data Pump is
>   available only on Oracle Database 10g release 1 (10.1) and later.